# Can a Rails controller action handle both html and javascript requests?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a link that allows users to claim fictional locations in my app, via the link

```
<%= link_to("Claim this location!", loc_claim_path(@loc.id), :id => "loc_claim") %>
```

It routes the request through my claim controller, like such:

```
def claim

    @loc = Location.find(params[:loc_id])

    if !@user
        flash[:notice] = "You need to be logged in to claim a location!"
        redirect_to(@loc)
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Location claimed!"
        render("claim.js")
    end

end
```

If a user isn't logged in (that is @user is false), it redirects them back to the location page.

However, if a user is logged in, then it needs to fire the javascript claim.js, which then also redirects back to the location page when finished.

My problem is, if set :remote => true, it will launch the javascript, but not the html, and vice versa when I don't set :remote.

Is there a way for me to have the best of both worlds? Or, barring that, is there a better way to set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works for me.

I set :remote => true on the link_to, which sends an a JS request to the claim controller, where I used

```
render js: "window.location.pathname='/locations/#{@location.id}'"
```

Which accomplishes the same thing as redirect_to(@loc)

Then I just rendered the claim.js request as normal, i.e.

```
render "claim"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with a respond_to block

```
 respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
```

For testing try disabling JavaScript and making sure the HTML path works

Comment: I've tried this, too. However, it keeps trying to render claim.js as an html page and locking up...

Comment: To clarify, I'm not building a controller to handle both html and javascript requests.
I want my controller to render an html request as html in some circumstances and as javascript in others.